# Excel, VBA code overshoots last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm puzzled to why my code overshoots the last row. If I run it on a worksheet with 30,000 rows it fills down to about 300k. This sheet calculates all my clients trades. Little confused at which way would be the most efficient way to calculate, use a vlookup function on each row which i insert using VBA or by using VBA to just calculate the total and display in a cell. Here's my code:

```
Sub UPDATE()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRow = Sheets("Closed Trades").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = Sheets("Open Orders").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets("Closed Trades")
    .Range("Q3:Q3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-13],10),""."",""/"")"
    .Range("R3:R3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-9],10),""."",""/"")"
    .Range("S3:S3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-13],'Symbols & Spreads'!C[-18]:C[-16],3,FALSE)"
    .Range("T3:T3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-14],'Symbols & Spreads'!C[-19]:C[-14],6,FALSE)"
    .Range("U3:U3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-15],'Symbols & Spreads'!C[-20]:C[-13],8,FALSE)*RC[-14]"
    .Range("V3:V3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=""eur"",RC[-1]*R6C25,RC[-1]/(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],C[2]:C[3],2,FALSE)))"
End With
With Sheets("Open Orders")
    .Range("T3:T3" & lastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-17],10),""."",""/"")"
    .Range("U3:U3" & lastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-16],'Symbols & Spreads'!C[-20]:C[-18],3,FALSE)"
    .Range("V3:V3" & lastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-17],'Symbols & Spreads'!C[-21]:C[-16],6,FALSE)"
    .Range("W3:W3" & lastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-18],'Symbols & Spreads'!C[-22]:C[-15],8,FALSE)*RC[-17]"
    .Range("X3:X3" & lastRow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=""eur"",RC[-1]*R6C27,RC[-1]/(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],C[2]:C[3],2,FALSE)))"
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As already answered, removing the extra '3' is the solution. But what made you append that 3 like `"Q3:Q3" & lastRow`. Are you not conceptually clear with range references or you overlooked that.

Comment: Ok so i made the changes and all it does is now fill up one row? Doesn't fill down. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ok so if i just put:

.Range("Q3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-13],10),""."",""/"")"

Then it will automatically fill down without asking it to. The data that its reference is connected to another excel workbook. I think i can work with this but a little confused to why it automatically fills down

Comment: Refer the answers given below - `.Range("Q3:Q" & lastRow)` will work. `.Range("Q3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-13],10),""."",""/"")" ` will not work. It will put the formula in just 1 cell and not fill down automatically

Comment: Hello, if i just use .Range("Q3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-13],10),""."",""/"")"  , it automatically fills down, i think its because of the adata connection i have on the same page. If i perform this on the next column and leave a blank space between the data connection and the formula, it doesn't fill down. But great my query is answered, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You must replace:

```
.Range("Q3:Q3" & lastRow)
```

with:

```
.Range("Q3:Q" & lastRow)
```

etc.

The extra **3** is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing

```
lastRow = Sheets("Closed Trades").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

to

```
lastRow = Sheets("Closed Trades").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

***AND***

```
.Range("Q3:Q3" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-13],10),""."",""/"")"
```

to

```
.Range("Q3:Q" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(RC[-13],10),""."",""/"")"
```

Comment: ***Remove last 3 from  "Q3:Q3"***